# Showing only one column

Tags: jquery, html-table

How is it possible to show only one column by default using jQuery. With dropdown-Selection, you can choose the other options. See here: 
[jquery hide columns in table based on dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427922/jquery-hide-columns-in-table-based-on-dropdown-select)

It works, but on initial start it shows all columns.

https://jsfiddle.net/db1844/0dtpy6oz/4/

Table:

```
<span class="dropdown-db-wrapper"><select id="sel"><option value="column-2">RFT 
3/2</option>
<option value="column-3">RFT 3/3</option>
<option value="column-4">RFT 3/4</option>
<option value="column-5">RFT 3/5</option>
<option value="column-6">RFT 3/6</option>
</select>
</span>

<table id="tablepress-105-no-2" class="tablepress tablepress-id-105 wctable">
<thead>
<tr class="row-1">
<th class="column-1"><strong>Typ</strong></th>
<th class="column-2 column two"><span style="font-size:10px">Tisch</span><br />
<strong>RFT 3/2</strong></th>
<th class="column-3 column three"><span style="font-size:10px">Tisch</span><br             
/>
<strong>RFT 3/3</strong></th>
<th class="column-4 column four"><span style="font-size:10px">Tisch</span><br 
/>
<strong>RFT 3/4</strong></th>
<th class="column-5 column five"><span style="font-size:10px">Tisch</span><br     
/>
<strong>RFT 3/5</strong></th>
<th class="column-6 column six"><span style="font-size:10px">Tisch</span><br />
<strong>RFT 3/6</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="row-hover">
<tr class="row-2">
<td class="column-1">Höhe des Tisches<sup>1</sup></td>
<td class="column-2 column two">780</td>
<td class="column-3 column three">780</td>
<td class="column-4 column four">780</td>
<td class="column-5 column five">780</td>
<td class="column-6 column six">780</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-3">
<td class="column-1">Breite des Tisches mit Wasserrinne<sup>1</sup></td>
<td class="column-2 column two">1150</td>
<td class="column-3 column three">1650</td>
<td class="column-4 column four">2150</td>
<td class="column-5 column five">2650</td>
<td class="column-6 column six">3150</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-4">
<td class="column-1">Tisch Aufspannfläche (BxT)<sup>1</sup></td>
<td class="column-2 column two">1000 x 350</td>
<td class="column-3 column three">1500 x 350</td>
<td class="column-4 column four">2000 x 350</td>
<td class="column-5 column five">2500 x 350</td>
<td class="column-6 column six">3000 x 350</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-5">
<td class="column-1">T-nuten (Anzahl x Breite x Abstand)<sup>1</sup></td>
<td class="column-2 column two">2 x 12 x 224</td>
<td class="column-3 column three">2 x 12 x 224</td>
<td class="column-4 column four">2 x 12 x 224</td>
<td class="column-5 column five">2 x 12 x 224</td>
<td class="column-6 column six">2 x 12 x 224</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-6">
<td class="column-1">Gewicht ohne Oberteil</td>
<td class="column-2 column two">350 kg</td>
<td class="column-3 column three">520 kg</td>
<td class="column-4 column four">680 kg</td>
<td class="column-5 column five">840 kg</td>
<td class="column-6 column six">990 kg</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-7">
<td class="column-1">Anzahl der Oberteile max.</td>
<td class="column-2 column two">2</td>
<td class="column-3 column three">3</td>
<td class="column-4 column four">4</td>
<td class="column-5 column five">5</td>
<td class="column-6 column six">6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
$j('#sel').on('change', function () {
var val = $j(this).val(), 
target = '.' + val;

$j('.column').hide();
$j(target).show();
});
});
```

Comment: instead of referencing to an old question, post your actual code, what you have tried so far and we can try to help you fix it

Comment: Just execute the code on the proper event (`domcontentloaded`?).

Answer (score 1):

On initial page load you should hide all column.Then according to the select box value you should allow the class show or hide.
 Check this code

```
 $('.choice').hide();
 if($('#sel').val() == 'one'){
   $('.one').show()
 }else{
  $('.two').show()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, It works now!!!